# QNEAT3 : Get gdal.Open error when trying to use any Iso-Area function that uses the calcIsoPolygons function

Tags: gdal

I am trying to discern if I have a user-error problem or if there is an issue with the **QNEAT3** plugin.

With QGIS 3.28, and on Mac OS 12, Windows 11, and Ubuntu 22, I am trying to make isochrones from a point field to a line network, and the plugin fails to say that `the result of gdal.Open (of presumably the temporary tif file) is None`.

The data seems fine because it will actually work for the IsoAreaAsPointcloud option, so I feel like there is a dependency issue or something but I figure I would not be the first person running into this error on three different platforms.

Has anyone else had this issue?

The current issue I have made in Github for this is https://github.com/root676/QNEAT3/issues/60

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this was user error after all.

My assumption that changing the CRS of the line file to UTM 11N was making the file valid was incorrect.  Once I used ogr2ogr to ensure the geojson was EPSG:3741 when I loaded the layer it worked fine.

So this not a QNEAT issue as much as a QGIS (or probably any GIS system) issue where projections and transforms are a little too opaque to the user.  Or to me at least.